# location.replace with php variables

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to redirect to a specific page once an if condition is satisfied. The php also needs to send out an alert at the same time. I'm very new to all of this so correct me if I'm wrong, but to send out an alert and also redirect, javascript must be used because PHP can't do both. So I've got a couple of php variables that need to be accessed by the script. I think the problem is there but I'm not sure.

```
echo "<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
    alert('$message');
    window.location.replace(\"http://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/Cart-MiniAddProduct?pid="+"<?php echo $style ?>" + "_"+"<?php echo $size8 ?>"+"&masterPid="+"<?php echo $style ?>"\");
    </SCRIPT>";
```

I keep getting a parsing error. `'parse error, expecting`','' `or` `';''` is the error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do not need to `echo` the variable inside `echo`. Just concatenate them.

Comment: @SougataBose I did that and still get the same parsing error unfortunately. I was just trying different things

Comment: @LonnieBest Yeah I'm not sure about it, I've tried with and without it and still get the same error on the same line

Comment: You have a lot of unescaped double-quotes. Avoid all this mess, see my conceptual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in php:

```
$style = "someStyle";
$myJS = <<<EOT
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.location.replace("http://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/Cart-MiniAddProduct?pid=$style");
</script>
EOT;

echo($myJS);
```

I know this is just a portion of the url, but I'm just trying to give you the concept. Notice how I put $style into this multi-line string.

Comment: much more readable

Comment: Thanks, so since its js I concatenate with a + ?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do it:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
alert(\'' . $message . '\');
window.location.replace(\'http://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/Cart-MiniAddProduct?pid=' . $style . '_' . $size8 . '&masterPid=' . $style . '\')</script>';
```

Comment: Getting a blank page now. I tried to replace the link with google and got a parsing error at the end of the program instead.

Comment: Can you copy & paste the link it generated here so I can see it?